# How to have the counter of characters when I am writing a texto (SMS)?

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, sms, internationalization

I have my new iPhone 6S, on iOS 9.

**I would like to have the counter of characters when I am writing a texto (SMS). How can I have that?**

I have turned on the setting for that. But for some recipients that does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that this setting is not working only for people you are sending an iMessage rather than a normal SMS?

Comment: I am writing a SMS. And the counter is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Character count setting in iPhone Settings is only for SMS messages.  It doesn't work for apps from other developers.  You would need to contact the developer of Texto to determine how to do character counts.

Comment: Texto is a word meaning SMS. I use the app Messages by Apple, that came with my iPhone.

Comment: Ok, there was a messaging app on the store named Texto so I thought that's what you meant.  Character count, when turned on in Settings, don't work for iMessages (iphone to iphone, for example).